# Null values overwriting empty strings

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Can somebody give me help on a small problem
I have a diary table, with 24 slots.
I can update a slot  with set xx where xx =''  and it works fine.
however if I try to update the whole table (edit) it then sets any empty rows to NULL., which means xx='' fails.
How can I stop the NULL Values overwriting empty slots do I set the default to ''?
They are all text fields at the moment set to Null-yes Default-NULL
or do I simply alter the update statement to Where xx=''OR IS NULL

Comment: It would help if you could please share the queries you are using to manipulate the database.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 
 [**Tips better SQL Question**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056)

Comment: Its not that complicated i have a diary table with 24 slots, I use a simple update statement update slot 18 if its empty '' which works., 
All the slots are set to NULL, I have cleared all null Values , no problem., however when i manually edit the table and update a slot, it then sets the rest of the empty slots to NULL,as the default is NULL, this means my original update statement doesn't work as it regards null as being not empty.